# Need to Escape the Character After Special Characters in Python's regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
line = 'div><div class="fieldRow jr_name"><div class="fieldLabel">name<'
regex0 = re.compile('(.+?)\v class="fieldLabel">name.+?', re.VERBOSE | re.UNICODE)
regex1 = re.compile('(.+?)v class="fieldLabel">name.+?', re.VERBOSE | re.UNICODE)
regex2 = re.compile('(.+?) class="fieldLabel">name.+?', re.VERBOSE | re.UNICODE)

m0 = regex0.match(line)
m1 = regex1.match(line)
m2 = regex2.match(line)

if m0:
    print 'regex0 is good'
else:
    print 'regex0 is no good'

if m1:
    print 'regex1 is good'
else:
    print 'regex1 is no good'

if m2:
    print 'regex2 is good'
else:
    print 'regex2 is no good'
```

The output is

```
regex0 is good
regex1 is no good
regex2 is good
```

I don't quite understand why I need to escape the character 'v' after "(.+?)" in regex0.  If I don't escape, which will become regex1, then the matching will fail.  However, for space right after "(.+?)" in regex3, I don't have to escape.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange enough.  Python 2.7.5 says it matches.

Comment: my guess is: `\v` being interpreted as a space, it matches. Try `\t` or `\s` it also works. But I'm puzzled....

Comment: I am puzzled as well. Why `\v` is treated differently?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there are some issues with your approach
The ones that contribute to your specific complaint are:

- You do not mark te regexp string as raw (`r'` prefix) - that makes the Python compiler change some "\" prefixed characters inside the string before they even reach the re.match call.
- "\v" happens to be one such character - a vertical tab that is replaced by "\0x0b"
- You use the  "re.VERBOSE" flag - that simply tells the regexp engine to ignore any whitesapce character. "\v" being a vertical tab is one character in this class and is ignored.

So, there is your match for regex0: the letter "v" os never seem as such.

Now, for the possible fixes on you approach, in the order that you should be trying to do them:

1) Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Really. There are a lot of packages that can do a good job on parsing HTML, and in missing those you can use stdlib's own `HTMLParser` (`html.parser` in Python3);

2) If possible, use Python 3 instead of Python 2 - you will be bitten on the first non-ASCII character inside yourt HTML body if you go on with the naive approach of treating Python2 strings as "real life" text. Python 3 automatic encoding handling (and explicit settings allowed to you when it is not automatic) .

Since you are probably not changing anyway, so try to use `regex.findall` instead of `regex.match` - this returns a list of matching strings and could retreive the attributes you are looking at once, without searching from the beggining of the file, or depending on line-breaks inside the HTML.

Comment: Thanks @jsbueno Yes, I did read others' posts about using some HTML parsers instead.  However, I just try to avoid dealing with malformed HTML content later.  re.VERBOSE is the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a special symbol in Python regex \v, about which you can read here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Python regex usually are written in `r'your regex'` block, where "r" means raw string. (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

In your code all special characters should be escaped to be understood as normal characters. E.g. if you write s - this is space, \s is just "s". To make it work in an opposite way use raw strings.
The line below is the solution you need, I believe.

```
regex1 = re.compile(r'(.+?)v class="fieldLabel">name.+?', re.VERBOSE | re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I just prefixed all regular expression with 'r' as you suggested.  It does affect the result of regex0.match(); however, regex1.match() still returns None.

Comment: \s in regex is "when the UNICODE flag is not specified, it matches any whitespace character" according to the python documentation that you've linked